# StackedAreaChart's default coloring policy after 8 colors on subsequent data repopulations

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to understand how the `StackedAreaChart` colors its series, in order to color series consistently in my application when data is replaced with entirely new data. Initially, I thought `StackedAreaChart` cycles through 8 default colors. In other words, data series are colored according to their index in `getData()`, mod 8. But I am encountering unexpected behavior:

[image]

The output above comes from the application below, which clears the `StackedAreaChart`'s data and repopulates it with 10 new series every time the window is clicked. As you can see, only the first 8 colors are consistent across clicks/repopulations.

```
public class TestChartColors extends Application {

    private int clickCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);
        final StackedAreaChart<Number,Number> chart = new StackedAreaChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.setAnimated(false);

        chart.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            clickCount++;
            chart.getData().clear();
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                chart.getData().add(flatSeries());
            }
            primaryStage.setTitle("After " + clickCount + " clicks.");
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Click the window.");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Series<Number,Number> flatSeries(){
        Series<Number,Number> s = new Series<>();
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> d = s.getData();
        d.add(new XYChart.Data<>(0, 1));
        d.add(new XYChart.Data<>(10, 1));
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround found:

Insert

```
while(chart.getData().size() % 8 != 0){
    final XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(0,0));             
    chart.getData().add(series);
}
```

before `chart.getData().clear();`.

StackedAreaChart seems to continue the numbering where it left off, except, strangely, for the first 8 colors.